# Return column from table when updating table from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to update one row in the `Payments` table and get several column values of this row

```
public void update(Int64 id , int status)
{
   dal.DoCommand("Payments_Update", new SqlParameter("@Id", id), new SqlParameter("@Status", status));

   // I WANT GET p_amount , p_credit ,p_debtor OF tbl_Payments HERE
   // 
}
```

In the above I call `DoCommand` function of DAL class

```
public void DoCommand(string sqlCmd, params SqlParameter[] parms)
{
   command.CommandText = sqlCmd;
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command.Parameters.Clear();
   command.Parameters.AddRange(parms);
   command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

and this is `Payments_update` procedure

```
alter procedure dbo.Payments_Update
   (@Id bigint,
    @Status int)
as
   update tbl_Payments
   set p_status = @Status
   where p_id = @Id

   return
```

and these are the columns of my `payments` table

```
p_amount int, p_creditor int, p_debtor int
```

Comment: please provide exact error with screen shots . it will be easy for others to understand your problem .

Comment: no i have not error i want get value of p_amount and p_amount and p_amount in update function

Comment: @Mohammadhossein Please notice to your copy-paste. You've pasted p_amount 3 times.

Comment: +1 for providing everything required to answer the question. One suggestion, though: Next time, be very explicit about what you're trying to achieve, and where your current solution falls short of the goal. Don't hide your actual question behind (1) a "I want …", (this risks triggering unhelpful "So why don't you …?" / "not a real question" responses) and (2) as a comment in a code block (easily overlooked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you simply alter your SP (Stored-Procedure) to select the required columns after the update.

```
alter procedure dbo.UpdateAndGetPaymentDetails
   (@Id bigint,
    @Status int)
as
   update tbl_Payments
   set p_status = @Status
   where p_id = @Id
   select p_amount, p_creditor, p_debtor
   from dbo.tbl_Payments
   where p_id = @Id
```

**Update:** As @i-one suggested in his answer, it's also possible to do it in one-pass using the [sql output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), look:

```
alter procedure dbo.UpdateAndGetPaymentDetails
    (@Id bigint,
    @Status int)
as
    update tbl_Payments
    set p_status = @Status
    output inserted.p_amount, inserted.p_creditor, inserted.p_debtor
    where p_id = @Id
```

In addition, I would suggest you to change the name of your SP to `UpdateAndGetPaymentDetails` because now you're performing `update` and `select` operations.

Later, you should work with the [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) method instead of the `ExecuteScalar` that you're using right now because you do want to select/return records while `ExecuteScalar` only returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. For example:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of update and then select, you may do it in one pass

```
alter procedure dbo.UpdateAndGetPaymentDetails
    (@Id bigint,
    @Status int)
as
    update tbl_Payments
    set p_status = @Status
    output inserted.p_amount, inserted.p_creditor, inserted.p_debtor
    where p_id = @Id
```

And then get values using `SqlDataReader` as suggested already.